# Cannot Get Total of Values in a Table Column Using Salesforce LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, html

I have a sample table which displays some custom object data:

[image]

On the last row, I am trying to get the total of **Column E** values under **AAA** row, but each time I test it on the org, there is no total displaying. Also, there are no errors when I compile it via Visual Studio Code.

Below are the current codes I am working on:

**sumLWC.html**

```
<!--portion from html file-->

<table>
<thead>
    <!--some code-->
</thead>

<tbody>         
    <template if:true={mData}>
        <template for:each={mData} for:item="keyVal">
            <tr key={keyVal.key} class="slds-hint-parent">
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="aDiv">{keyVal.key}</div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <template for:each={keyVal.value} for:item="mValue">
                        <div key={mValue.ColumnB}>
                            {mValue.ColumnB}
                        </div> 
                    </template>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <template for:each={keyVal.value} for:item="mValue2">
                        <div key={mValue2.ColumnC}>
                            {mValue2.ColumnC}
                        </div> 
                    </template>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <template for:each={keyVal.value} for:item="mValue3">
                        <div key={mValue3.ColumnD}>
                            {mValue3.ColumnD}
                        </div> 
                    </template>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <template for:each={keyVal.value} for:item="mValue4">
                        <div key={mValue4.ColumnE}>
                            {mValue4.ColumnE}
                        </div> 
                    </template>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </template>

        <template if:true={mData}>
            <tr class="slds-hint-parent">     
                <th scope="col" colspan="4">
                    <div><center>AAA Total</center></div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="aTotal" lwc:dom="manual" onload={computeSum}></div> 
                </th>
            </tr>          
        </template>
    </template> 
</tbody>
</table>
```

**sumLWC.js**

```
//portion from js file

computeSum(event) {

        const table = this.template.querySelector("table");
             
        totalVal = 0;

        for(var i=2;i<table.rows.length;i++) {
            if(this.template.querySelector(".aDiv").value === 'AAA') {
                totalVal = totalVal + (table.rows[i].cells[5].innerHTML);
                console.log('Total:' + totalVal);
                this.template.querySelector(".aTotal").innerHTML = totalVal; 
            }
        }

}
```

I already inserted `lwc:dom="manual` so `innerHTML` can be recognized, but I still don't get any result.

How can I get the sum of those three Column E values related to AAA?

Hoping someone could help me on this and lead me on the right direction.

Comment: This won't work for a multitude of reasons. Just sum the data you want into a variable, and then display that variable.

Comment: @sfdcfox that's what I am trying to do